# getting errors while trying to run ionic project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, moodle, moodle-mobile

I have downloaded open source project for moodle from github
I followed all the steps but when I run ionic serve or ionic build I get the following errors

[image]

I have searched a lot but could not find any clue

Comment: have you run `npm i` before `ionic serve`? also delete `package.lock.json` file and then do `npm i` again

Comment: yes I did same error

Comment: can you share github link of that repo?.

Comment: https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp

Comment: I am also get this warn : npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.7 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@11.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: and this one : npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=4.0 <4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: could it be the problem

Comment: Delete `mode_modules` folder and try again.